# Post content area too wide - what css is missing?

Tags: css

I'm using BuddyPress with BP Simple Front End Post to allow people to post from the front end of this site. However, the Post Content area fills the whole screen.  I started trying to narrow it down and force it to fit in the area allowed, but every time I add something to the css another set of tools pops out too far. I've added an insane number of elements to the css and bits are still all askew, so I must be missing something obvious.

```
#wp-new-post-desc-editor-container, 
#wp-new-post-desc-editor-tools,
#new-post-desc_toolbargroup, 
.wp-editor-wrap, 
.wp_themeSkin table, 
.wp-editor-container, 
.mceToolbar, 
new-post-desc_toolbargroup, 
wp_themeSkin table,
.wp-editor-container,
.quicktags-toolbar, 
.wp_themeSkin tr.mceFirst td.mceToolbar, 
mceToolbar, 
#new-post-desc_toolbargroup,
#wp-editor-container,
#new-post-desc_toolbar2 tr,
.mceToolbar mceToolbarRow2,
#wpuf_new_post_form,
#new-post-desc_toolbar1,
.mceToolbar mceToolbarRow1,
.wp_themeSkin table, 
.wp_themeSkin tbody, 
.wp_themeSkin a, 
.wp_themeSkin img, 
.wp_themeSkin tr, 
.wp_themeSkin div, 
.wp_themeSkin td, 
.wp_themeSkin iframe, 
.wp_themeSkin span, 
.wp_themeSkin *, 
.wp_themeSkin, 
.mceText
{
width:600px !important; 
}
```

The page is:
http://emgraphics.net/legacytest/post-a-story/
Login: stack
PW: test
Go to Post a Story

Here's what it looks like sans css and after all this foolishness. I must be missing something blindingly obvious?[image]

[image]

Comment: Making us log into your site to test something is annoying, you're not likely to get much aid this way. Try reproducing the issue in a jsFiddle or something similar if you hope to get a quicker response

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want spammers posting a ton of junk with this out there, so it needs a login. Anyway, all users need to login to view it as it is part of the system - not even sure how I'd change that. Haven't the foggiest what to do with the jsFiddle and it contains no instructions that I can find.  It doesn't seem to have anything to do with finding a specific css problem.  Or is it your company and you're just trying to pitch it?

Comment: I have no relation to jsFiddle, haha. It's quite a common site here on SO because of it's usefulness in allowing others to see how your code works. In using it you would copy over the relevant HTML and CSS in a simplified way in order to try and reproduce the issue. You don't have to by any means, but it would make helping you much easier

Comment: I can see where it may be useful fixing an error on a single file, but this is pulling up the Post function into the front-end of WP.  So I'm guessing this is coming from multiple php and css files, both in the core WP program and plugins. Also, it's not an error per se, just can't get the stupid thing to fit in the page properly.  Will bookmark jsFiddle for future reference though.

Comment: The CSS doesn't _cause_ any problems, it only makes the problems _visible_! You have a table on that page with 16 `td`s next to each other, each with a button bar in it. Without the CSS, only the leftmost `td` is visible, because the rest is out of the viewport. Make the contents narrower, and the rest shows up too. What has caused this abundance of button bars, no idea.

Comment: Access has been blocked.

Your IP [] has been identified as spam .Remove span to check .I would like to check it now 

Protected by: AVH First Defense Against Spam

Comment: I can do it please let me try it .